# ngIf inner ngFor ionic2

Tags: angular, ionic2, ngfor, angular-ng-if

In the following Ionic2/Angular2 template:

```
<ion-row style="background-color: #f4b434">
    <ion-col col-4><b>Brand</b></ion-col>
    <ion-col col-1><b>Qty</b></ion-col>
    <ion-col col-2><b>Sales</b></ion-col>
    <ion-col col-2 style="color: whitesmoke "><b>Qty</b></ion-col>
    <ion-col col-3 style="color: whitesmoke "><b>Sales</b></ion-col>
</ion-row>
<div *ngFor="let x of datasales">
    <ion-row>
        <ion-col col-4><b>{{x.Brand}}</b></ion-col>
        <ion-col col-1>{{x.Qty_Today | number:0 }}</ion-col>
        <ion-col col-2>{{x.SalesToday | number:0 }}</ion-col>
        <ion-col col-2>{{x.Qty_MTD | number:0 }}</ion-col>
        <ion-col col-3>{{x.Sales_MTD | number:0 }}</ion-col> 
    </ion-row> 
</div>
```

If `x.Brand = 'Good'` then in the second `ion-row` I want to add `style="background- color:red"`.

How can I accomplish it?

Answer (score 3):

You may use `ngStyle` as per [Angular 2 docs](https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle), eg. like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let x of datasales"> 
  <ion-row [ngStyle]="{'background-color' : x.Brand==='Good'? 'red' : ''}">
    <ion-col col-4><b>{{x.Brand}}</b></ion-col>
    ...
  </ion-row> 
</div>
```

**Please note**:

1. don't forget the square brackets around `ngStyle`
2. the value of `ngStyle` is a key:value hash, where the `key`s are CSS property names, and the `value`s are expressions. In the above case, I used a test on x.Brand to decide which value should be assigned to the `background-color` property of the `div`.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to Paolos answer, when only affecting one property, you can use the `[style.prop]="expr"` syntax, where prop is the css property you want to affect, and expr is the expression you want to evaluate.

```
<ion-row [style.background-color]="x.Brand==='Good'?'red':''">
</ion-row>
```

This also works similar with `ngClass`, as you can use `[class.className]="expr"` to apply `.className` if `expr` is true. As such you can add a class to your styles

```
.is-good-brand {
  background-color: red;
}
```

and in your template use

```
<ion-row [class.is-good-brand]="x.Brand==='Good'">
</ion-row>
```

Since you only want to apply a style if the condition is fulfilled.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ngStyle like this;

```
<ion-row style="background-color: #f4b434">
    <ion-col col-4><b>Brand</b></ion-col>
    <ion-col col-1><b>Qty</b></ion-col>
    <ion-col col-2><b>Sales</b></ion-col>
    <ion-col col-2 style="color: whitesmoke "><b>Qty</b></ion-col>
    <ion-col col-3 style="color: whitesmoke "><b>Sales</b></ion-col>
</ion-row>
<div *ngFor="let x of datasales"
    [ngStyle]="{backgroundcolor: x.brand='Good' ? 'red' : 'transparent'}">
    <ion-row>
        <ion-col col-4><b>{{x.Brand}}</b></ion-col>
        <ion-col col-1>{{x.Qty_Today | number:0 }}</ion-col>
        <ion-col col-2>{{x.SalesToday | number:0 }}</ion-col>
        <ion-col col-2>{{x.Qty_MTD | number:0 }}</ion-col>
        <ion-col col-3>{{x.Sales_MTD | number:0 }}</ion-col> 
    </ion-row> 
</div>
```